Reactivate service worker from popup window.onload
I'm working on a chrome extension where the service worker does all the heavy lifting (functionality, authentication, etc.), and the popup handles the UI. It basically works like this the popup script (popup.js) sends a message to the SW and depending on the response it shows a different screen (interface). Essentially the SW listens for 2 things, a message and/or webRequests. SW code below:
(async () => {
  //put id here
  id = await chrome.storage.sync.get("myID");

  chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(callback, filter, []);

  //accept message from popup asking for login status
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((req, _, sendResponse) => { ...
    })
  // accepts message from popup for other functionality
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((req, _, sendResponse) => { ...
  });
})();

PROBLEM OCCURS when no handler for the listeners is triggered soon enough and the SW goes inactive. When the popup is eventually opened the SW worker is still inactive and there is no one listening for the message from the popup. Is there a way I can reactivate the SW and check if it is currently active.
I am considering making a persistent service worker but that is not necessary as I only need it to be active when the popup is opened. This would be my last resort.


Register the listeners before await in order for them to receive a message and wake up the background script. 2) Open a port via chrome.runtime.connect and send a dummy message every 29 seconds or less. This will keep the service worker running as long as the popup is open.


My problem occurs if the popup is not open BEFORE the SW goes inactive I already have contingencies to keep it active AFTER interacting with the popup

If you implement these suggestions the order won't matter.

Thanks all I had to do was move the await like you said and it works now

I couldn't choose woxxom's answer as the answer but removing the await fixed the problem and even when the service worker goes to sleep it wakes back up when it receives a message. Here's some more information in the chrome extension docs on the lifecycle of service workers.
